# What species is this bushy thorny yellow-flowered angiosperm from Morocco?

Tags: species-identification, botany

What species is this bushy thorny yellow-flowered angiosperm from Morocco? Photographed in spring in a dried up river bed. The bush is about 1 metre high. [image: bush]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I happened to come across a photo of a similar leafless shrub (without flowers) that also had 120 degree branches and looked thorny, or Spiny is probably a better description. It helped me to identify the plant in your photo as a Launaea arborescens. It is an unusual species of Chicory in the dandelion family, Asteraceae. Being tolerant of arid locations, it native to northwest Africa and southern Spain.

http://encyclopaedia.alpinegardensociety.net/plants/Launaea/arborescens

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launaea

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launaea_arborescens

Comment: Well done user22542!  I thought it looked "chicory-ish" but that's about as far as I got.  I've been watching this question ever since hoping someone would figure it out.